# How can I parseInt a BigInteger but using StringTokenizer

Tags: java, string, biginteger, parseint, stringtokenizer

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // SPLASH 
    // OBJECTS 
    File file1 = new File ("DATA11.txt");
    File file2 = new File ("OUT11.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file1); 
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file2); 
    StringTokenizer st = null;

    // CONSTANTS 
    // VARIABLES 
    String sentence; 
    String reverse = ""; 
    int length; 
    boolean isNumber = false; 

    // INPUT 
    while (scanner.hasNextLine())
    {
        sentence = scanner.nextLine(); 
        length = sentence.length(); 
        for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            reverse += sentence.charAt(i); 
        }
        st = new StringTokenizer(reverse, " "); 
        try
        {
            Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()); 
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {

        }

    }
```

I'm doing a string activity assignment and I have to flip the sentence and the words but numbers cannot be reversed. I am using StringTokenizer to tokenize a txt file called DATA11.txt and writing in a file called OUT11.txt (I am aware I have not closed the reader and writer yet). I first flipped the whole sentence and letters regardless of if it is a number or not and then I check if it is an int that I can flip back (strings like 123abc are kept reverse). One of the lines in the file have a 22 character long integer. I was wondering how I can parseInt the tokenized string using BigInteger.

Here is the txt file:

llaw eht no reeb fo selttob 98 dnuora ti ssap nwod 1 ekat uoy reeb fo selttob 99 llaw eht no reeb fo selttob 99

0123456789

saera rellams 51 fo edam yllautca tnsi 15aerA

secalp lamiced 10 ot ip si 6356295141p3

elpmaxe rof 1212323423409234092340 ekil srebmun gnol ylaer daer ot drah fo dnik steg ti tub egaugnal looc ytterp a si cibarA

Answer (score 0):

Documentation is a good source of knowledge. If you want a `BigInteger` you should open documentation page about it and find what you are looking for. in your case it can be a constructor [description](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(java.lang.String)).

I should consider few updates to you code:

- understand when you should use string concatenation (`s += "a"`) and when it is better to use [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). String is an immutable object as a result every time shen you are making concatenation inside loop new string is created. To reverse 10 letters word you are creating 10 strings.
- you could prevent revert of number strings for example by:

  - split sentence into strings `public String[] split(String regex)`, [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)), regex in you case is a space;
  - iterate over strings;
  - verify if string is a numeric one by `public boolean matches(String regex)`, [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)), in this case regex should match only numbers `"\\d+"`.